# PDO Updates diferent columns same query

Tags: mysql, sql-update

Could you tell me what I am doing wrong?

I want to update 02 different tables in one query using PDO inside MySQL DB

This is my code:

```
            $dados = [
                'senha' => password_hash($_POST['senha'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT),
                'ativo' => '0',
                'email' => $_POST['email'],
            ];

            $sql = "
            UPDATE administradores, solicitacoes_reseta_senhas
            SET    senha = :senha, ativo = :ativo
            WHERE  email = :email and email = :email
            ";

            $stmt= $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute($dados);
```

And this the error I am getting from MySQL:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'email' in where clause is ambiguous

PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'email' in where clause is ambiguous
```

Below the structures of the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `solicitacoes_reseta_senhas` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `token` varchar(250) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NOT NULL,
  `data_expiracao` datetime NOT NULL,
  `ativo` int NOT NULL,
  `data_criacao` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `administradores` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome` varchar(120) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `sobrenome` varchar(120) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(120) DEFAULT NULL,
  `senha` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `apelido` varchar(80) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `sexo` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `telefone_fixo` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `telefone_celular` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `data_nascimento` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `observacao` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `data_criacao` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `data_atualizacao` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `adm_atualizacao` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ativo` tinyint DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`,`ativo`)
) ;
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: Use aliases for the tables.

Comment: Why not just issuing two `UPDATE`s in a transaction?

Comment: Hi @Jens thanks for your answer, could you give me an example?

Comment: Hi @stickybit thanks for your answer, I am trying to optimize the Command to prevent consume

Comment: That saves very, very little, if anything or if it doesn't even have a negative effect. The pages with the records to be changed still need to be found, loaded, changed and written back. One thing you could do that will likely help is to put an index on `solicitacoes_reseta_senhas.email` to support the `WHERE` clause of your statement.

Comment: @stickybit hm.. and in this case, how would be? I am not too good with technical languages like index hehe

Comment: @Sophie: Sorry, I don't understand your question? You want to know hos indexes work maybe? Basically they organize part of the data in a way, that it can be searched very efficiently. In detail that's a topic on its own, to much for a short answer in an SO comment. You need to do some own research here I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use aliases

```
  $dados = [
            'senha' => password_hash($_POST['senha'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT),
            'ativo' => '0',
            'email' => $_POST['email'],
        ];

        $sql = "
        UPDATE administradores a, solicitacoes_reseta_senhas s
        SET    senha = :senha, ativo = :ativo
        WHERE  a.email = :email and s.email = :email
        ";

        $stmt= $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute($dados);
```

Comment: Thank you soo much for your time and help, I used your logic and works, Just needed to add the same logic to Values